# Trying to create a select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im not sure if this site is only with asp, but I am trying to create a form in which the child fields are disabled or enabled based on whether you chose one or the other.  I was able to do it with a checkbox, but i want it to work with the drop down select value.  here is the link and the script below:

http://www.rfdesignstudio.com/newsite/paypal.html

Here is the select script:

```
<select name="type" class="input" id="type" onchange="type()">
      <option value="General">General</option>
      <option value="Walk-a-thon">Walk-a-thon</option>
</select>
```

and here is the function script:

```
function type(){

if (document.getElementById('type').value=='Walk-a-thon') { 
   document.getElementById('child').disabled = false; 
   document.getElementById('teacher').disabled = false; 
   document.getElementById('room').disabled = false; 
   } 
else { 
  document.getElementById('child').disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById('teacher').disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById('room').disabled = true; 
  document.getElementById('child').value = ""; 
  document.getElementById('teacher').value=""; 
  document.getElementById('room').value="";}
  }
```

Comment: Are you actually using jQuery, because your code example uses none.

Comment: yeah sorry i think i meant to say javascript.

Comment: any thoughts on how i can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reduce it to this (untested):

```
function type(){
  if ($('#type').val() == 'Walk-a-thon') { 
    $('#child, #teacher, #room').removeAttr('disabled');
  } 
  else { 
   $('#child, #teacher, #room').attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
  } 
}
```

And you probably also want to trigger this function when the document loads by adding this fragment somewhere in the `head` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){ type(); });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it but its not removing the disabled attribute.  any thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the page?  Can you step through with firebug to determine if the code is actually running as expected?

Comment: i have not clue on using firebug, i installed it and uploaded the file to this link http://www.rfdesignstudio.com/newsite/paypal2.html, but im not getting page errors from what i see.

Comment: The <script> fragment I gave you needs to be added after the <script> tag that loads jquery (which you have further down on the page).  And you shouldn't hardcode the 'disabled' attributes into the input tags, let jquery attribute setters handle that.

Comment: i really like your code, it helps simply the issue alot, it seems to be working fine now :-) i think you very much for your help.